# Measuring electric potential with a flame probe

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I'm reading up on an experiment to measure the electric potential at some point in space. There's a charged metal sphere that sets up an electric field in space. We want to measure the voltage at some point. The procedure of the experiment includes placing a flame at the tip of a needle that is connected to a voltmeter. The needle, and the flame at its tip, are some distance away from the sphere. It says that the role of the flame is to make sure that the potential at the needle tip has the value of the potential of the charged sphere at that point. But I don't understand that. On multiple sources, it says that the flame ionizes the air and the ionization current will flow until the potential at the needle tip is the same as the potential due to the charged sphere at that point. But I don't understand the role of the flame and the ionization. How does the ionization achieve that? And doesn't the ionization cause the sphere to attract opposite charges (ions) making its charge drop, along with the resulting field and potential? It seems like we're introducing a source of error, instead of a means of measurement.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the flame introduces ions in the atmosphere, which flow along the field lines. While you are right in saying that the charge on the sphere will also decrease, I believe it is connected to a battery that will maintain it at a constant potential. The only thing that can change now is the potential of the probe tip, which will eventually become equal to the potential of the sphere at that point